# How to use Javascript game engine with NAPA O365

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, craftyjs

I am looking to add a Javascript game to my Office 365 SharePoint site, and I can't seem to figure out how to add an engine such as Crafty https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on a folder in Napa and "upload" files to it. I don't have experience with the Game Engine you refer but I would imagine it should be a matter of uploading the correct JS files and then reference them in your pages.